# How to add line numbers inside a box?

Tags: mdframed, line-numbering

I have the following code and I would like to have individual line numbers for both first and second parts

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{mdframed}
            First part:\\
            first line \\
            second line\\
            Second part:\\
            something here
    \end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
```

Preferred format is

```
-------------------
| First part:     |
|1 first line     | 
|2 second line    |        
| Second part:    |                   
|1 something here |                   
-------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is your minimal complete code in tex format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `listings`, but is designed to put the line numbers at margin, without indenting the code, so you must add a tabulation to each line of code if you want to indent this number and the code like the items of a list.

On the other hand, the code will be printed as is, so you should not break lines with `\\`

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left,,basicstyle=\ttfamily, numbersep=-10pt,tabsize=4}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}
First part:
\begin{lstlisting}[name=Foo]
    first line 
    second line
\end{lstlisting}
Second part:
\begin{lstlisting}[name=Bah]
    something here 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```